# Formatar o Chronometer

Tags: android

Em minha aplicação inseri um chronometer que simula um tempo de jogo... mas quando eu clico em parar e depois em continuar ele me mostra em formato (00:00:00:00) e queria que me mostrasse novamente em (00:00)

OBS: me mostra em milisegundos

codigo:

```
private Chronometer reloginho;
long tempoPausado = 0;

     imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
            imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
            imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
            imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);


            imgButton_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgButton_play.setEnabled(false);
                    imgButton_pause.setEnabled(true);
                    imgButton_1.setEnabled(true);
                    imgButton_2.setEnabled(true);

                    reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    reloginho.start();
                    reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + tempoPausado);
                }
            });

            imgButton_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
                    imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
                    imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
                    imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);

                    tempoPausado = reloginho.getBase();
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    reloginho.stop();
                }
            });
```

Obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

Como voce disse já ter o texto formatado sendo exibido, deve ser em algum textview ou algo do tipo, estou certo? então, basta voce converter essa hora em uma string, tenta algo assim ó:

```
    //...
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date hora = reloginho.getInstance().getTime(); // Ou qualquer outra forma que tem
    String horaFormatada = sdf.format(hora);
    //...
    relogioTextView.setText(horaFormatada);
    //...
```

espero que seja isso!!

Saúde e Paz!

Comment: Bom dia amigo... não seria uma TextView sera a própria propriedade Chronometer... mesmo eu colando esse código ele me apresenta o erro no getInstance() e no relogioTextView troquei para reloginho.setText(...)